# Laptop shut down during upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 not being plugged it to power

Tags: boot, upgrade, bootloader

2 weeks ago I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.00 to 18.04 and all was fine.

Several days ago I got a notification for an upgrade, so I agreed and after that, I realized it was a long one again like upgrading from 16 to 18.04.

Unfortunately, I forgot to connect the laptop to power and the battery drained during the upgrade.

I have attached some a couple of pics of the screen I get while booting:

[image: here]

[image: here]

Sometimes the process stops at the screens with a **Green-colored [OK]** before lines, sometimes it stops to the screen with lines without the Green-colored [OK]in front.

What should I do, considering I do not want to lose the files I have on the laptop if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: I tried to add a second pic but it did not work. if it is important I can post a link to it.

LE: if I you click the no 1 in my post you can see also the other pic

Comment: Boot from live cd, copy needed files to usb flash or another hard drive. Reinstall Ubuntu. Chances you can recover from interrupted update are very little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No downtime during update!

But you can rescue your files hopefully :

- make USB drive with live system, e. g. Ubuntu
- boot from USB
- mount hard drive

Copy all needed files!

Answer (score 0):

You should never update your system while you are unplugged your charger.

When you want to update your system do the following steps:

1. Consider to charge your battery to 100% and stay on charging cable. In case of power outage, at least you will have a chance to finish the installation.
2. Consider to make a backup of all your necessary documents - do a backup to a cloud (whatever you using) or copy your files to separate drive. If something goes wrong during the update process, you will not lose your documents.
3. Consider preparing Live USB drive with some sort of rescue image in case you'll need to retrieve some files from broken file system.
4. Consider updating only on stable releases of SW, unless you are a beta tester, and you need to install unstable SW. This will lower the risk of unpredictable mistakes during the update process.

I'm your case I would recommend booting from Live USB and try to mount you fs in order to copy some files from it.

Also, consider reading this:
[upgrade gone bad, no ubuntu, no upgrade, no windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256241/upgrade-gone-bad-no-ubuntu-no-upgrade-no-windows)

Comment: thanks, but you can image i knew i should not update on battery only. :)